# Get AD Group the current user belongs to

Tags: excel, active-directory, vsto, ribbon-control

Get the groups the current user belongs to.
Briefly about the project:

1. i am working on a VSTO project for Excel using vb.NET
2. buttons are provided in Excel for the users.
3. these are to be assigned on the basis of the AD group

I want to read out the AD groups to which the user currently logged on to the computer belongs.

Are the groups retrieved from the AD cached on the PC.
If yes, it would be very easy to read them, but so far I could not find anything.
If not, how can I check which groups the user belongs to without having to fiddle with passwords?

Comment: Vlookup can check a name in a list or index() with match()

Comment: Are you thinking of using Outlook Object Model or AD API?

Comment: I need to find out which ActiveDirectory group the current user belongs to. What I have tried is to use the System.Security.Principal & System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory imports to get the groups. Unfortunately I got all sorts of things but not the correct groups. I'm not quite sure how the outlook object model should help me. I used the API but i do have to conneced with password which my customer do not want. I thought i can catch the groups at the current windows pc, where the program is running. is that possible?